# How to create an blog in drupal 7?

Tags: 7, nodes

We are creating a single page website responsive one. Planning to add a blog link. Can anyone specify how to create a blog page?

Comment: Hi, I've removed the part of the question about 'elegant design' as we can't help you with your design work here.

Answer (score 1):

Enable **Blog**  module  under **CORE**

[image]

Comment: So will it become responsive and we want to add the contents in a block so later the admin can make some changes.

Comment: As far as I know, that depends on your theme. If your theme supports responsive, yes it does

Comment: How to add the contents in a block after enabling the blog module

Comment: @NijiMonachan If you have another question please ask it separately. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[Blog Module](https://drupal.org/documentation/modules/blog)** in your Drupal 7. for more info kindly visit 
to learn [**How to create a blog site with Drupal step by step?**](http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/blog/drupal.htm)

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @MPD With question looking the way it looks now, I think it's as good answer as we possibly can get.

Comment: @MPD : sorry If i am wrong to answer as I am new bee but I think I have given link for reference only. We can't teach them step by step here.

Comment: @GaganGami No problem, this post had a flag on it, which is why I left the comment.  On other sites, link-only answers are deleted outright.  We tolerate them (to an extent) here, but prefer that people add more detail to answers.  While handholding and step-by-step answers aren't the best, a middle ground is often outlining the process in broad strokes, with links out to appropriate places for more information.